# Using @JsonTypeInfo annotation for generic object lists

Tags: java, json

I am trying to serialize and de-serialize (with Json and [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html)) an polymorphic list of Objects that have the following annotation on the base class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
```

When I write the object itself it does include the polymorphic property class in to its properties list, and when I write a list of these objects it does not include any information on the classes in this list.

Does someone know what is wrong or what to configure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong version 1.5.2 which has that [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-311) open. They have it fixed in 1.5.4